# how to list all properties of a variant type variable in c++ like console.log in javascript

Tags: javascript, c++

I want to list all the properties of a Variant type variable in c++

For example in JavaScript  console.log(variable) will show all the structure of this variable with its properties. I'm looking for something similar in c++. Because I work with a variable which i don't know, and I need to read all properties before i work with it.

I have no idea how to do this.

For example I have:

```
Variant input;
```

I want to see and list its structure and properties.

I know that Variant type is a structure in C++ and maybe like any data structures from memory its possible to get addresses or to separate data and pointers to that data. I'm sorry if i say something stupid, but I imagine the structure like a list of data with their pointers, so I need only to know the properties name, not necessary it's data.

Answer (score 1):

You can't randomly print out an object of any arbitrary type. C++ and JavaScript typically execute in *completely* different ways. Your best bet is to attach a debugger, set a breakpoint, then analyse `input` from within the debugger.

Without more details on what you have tried and what you are trying to do, this is as specific as I can be.

Comment: thank you for your answer, maybe somebody knows a work arround

Comment: @ManY: No, there is no "workaround" (other than using a debugger, which I already suggested: did you try it yet?). It is fundamentally impossible.

Comment: no i didnt tried it, i'm new to this area, i just want to see what other people think about question, maybe for somebody its not new. but anyway, thank you for your answer

Comment: @ManY: I know what I am talking about.

Comment: i have no doubt about that, but i want also to see others what think